# convert List<List<object>> to IList<IList<object>>

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have written a method which is 
    `public List<List<object>> Fetch(string data)`, 
inside I create 
    `List<List<object>> p = new List<List<object>>();`

my boss now wants to return a `IList<IList<object>>` instead of `List<List<object>>` ie
    `public IList<IList<object>> Fetch(string data)`,

so when I try do
    `return (IList<IList<object>>) p; //throws an exception`

How do I convert 
  `List<List<object>>` to `IList<IList<object>>`  and back to `List<List<object>>`

Comment: If you need to convert it back your design is most likely broken.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can't perform that conversion via straight casting - it wouldn't be safe. Instead, you should use:

```
IList<IList<object>> ret = new List<IList<object>>();
```

Then for each "sublist" you can use:

```
// Or whatever
ret.Add(new List<object>());
```

Finally, just return `ret`.

You *could* use LINQ to perform the conversion of your existing `List<List<object>>` when you return it - but it would be better to just create a more appropriate type to start with, as shown above.

---

To understand why some of the existing answers are wrong, suppose you *could* do this:

```
IList<IList<object>> p = new List<List<object>>();
```

Then this would be valid:

```
List<List<object>> listOfLists = new List<List<object>>();
IList<IList<object>> p = listOfLists;
p.Add(new object[]);
List<object> list = p[0];
```

But `p[0]` is a reference to an `object[]`, not a `List<object>`... our supposedly type-safe code doesn't look as safe any more...

Fortunately, `IList<T>` is invariant to prevent exactly this problem.

Comment: Are you hinting that List<object> could be replaced with object[]. Are you sure your example is correct in second part?

Comment: @HasanKhan: I'm saying that `object[]` implements `IList<object>`, so can be added to any `IList<IList<object>>` - it would be a bad thing if the last block of code *did* compile. Fortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh didn't know array also implements IList

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks for the answer and also the detailed explanation.

Comment: @JonSkeet What about `IList<IList<double>> listOfList = tabOfTab;` where `tabOfTab` is `double[][]` ?

Comment: @DineMartin: What about it? I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet IList<T> is invariant but I can cast tabOfTab to an IList<IList<double>>

Comment: @DineMartin: That would be due to array variance, e.g. how a `string[]` can be viewed as `object[]`.

Comment: @JonSkeet But I cannot convert double[] to type object[]

Comment: @DineMartine: No, because double is a value type. This is all getting a bit off the point. I suggest you try to find a related question or ask a new one.

Comment: this becomes very weird with `IList<ILIst<T> = ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<T>>`

Answer (score 14):

You would have to declare your list as

```
IList<IList<object>> list = new List<IList<object>>(); // Works!
```

This works, because only the outer list is created in the first place. You can then insert individual items that are compatible with `IList<object>`:

```
list.Add(new List<object>());
list.Add(new object[10]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var myOriginalList = new List<List<Object>>();
var converted = ((IList<IList<Object>>)myOriginalList.Cast<IList<Object>>().ToList()); // EDIT: Added .ToList() here
```

You shouldn't need to convert back- you can do just about anything on `IList` that you could on `List`.

Comment: Why bother creating a new list though? It's simpler just to create the right type to start with.

Comment: Agreed 100%, and your approach explains that well.  I leave this up to show that if you needed to do it (e.g. the off chance a third party library returned a `List<List<Object>>` that you needed to convert for another 3rd party library), you can do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the declaration of the result variable from `List<List<object>` to `IList<IList<object>>`

Which you can instantiate against `List<IList<object>>`

And each item in the result can be of type `List<object>`

```
    static IList<IList<object>> Test()
    {
        IList<IList<object>> result = new List<IList<object>>();
        var item = new List<object>() { "one", "two", "three" };
        result.Add(item);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public IList<IList<object>> Fetch(string data)
{
  IList<IList<object>> p = new List<IList<object>>();

  // add your stuff here

  return p;
}
```

Comment: @vidstige JonSkeet was correct for about 30 seconds.. I originally had IList<IList<object>> p = new List<List<object>>();  which would not compile, and shouldn't.  I noticed my mistake like 10 seconds after posting.  TEN SECONDS.  Further proof that JonSkeet is actually a bot. =)  I don't know who that was talking to Hanselman the other day...

Comment: lol thats quick alright. But I cannot see that your post was edited? Perhaps there is some 'quiet time' where you can editit it without beeing a new revision...

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` and `IList<T>` do not support covariance. So this does not compile:

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<IList<string>>(); // DOES NOT COMPILE!!!!!
```

Comment: `List<T>` is already of Type `IList<T>`  No co- (or contra-)variance is required.

Comment: @AllenG so can you explain why that snippet I have put does not compile?

Comment: @AllenG: Yes, contravariance *is* required here, because a `List<List<string>>` isn't a `List<IList<string>>`. Did you try to compile the code Aliostad said won't compile? It really won't.

Comment: I added my comment before you added your snippet.  List<List<T>> should be a valid return on a Method with a signature of IList<IList<T>>.

Comment: @AllenG that still does not justify downvote. The problem OP experiences is the result of lack of covariance/contravariance in ILst and List.

Comment: @AllenG: No, it absolutely should not. There are too many lists here. Should List<Box> be a valid return for a method typed as returning IList<Box>? Yes. Should List<Box> be a valid return for a method typed as returning IList<IContainer>? **No, absolutely not**. The caller reasonably expects that they can insert a Bottle into an IList<IContainer> but what you have in hand is a List<Box> that cannot contain a Bottle. Therefore the conversion must be illegal.