# C# Parameter of IList<IList<(ClassType)>>

Tags: c#, list, generics, parameters, casting

I can't seem to figure out why the following doesn't work.

From reading around it seems it must be somehow related to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006016).

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public void SomeFunction(IList<IList<T>> ListOfLists)
    {
    }
}

....

List<List<SimpleClass>> lists = new List<List<SimpleClass>>();
new Test<SimpleClass>().SomeFunction( (IList<IList<SimpleClass>>)lists );
```

How can I require a list to actually be a list of lists? I can't seem to grasp what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `List<List<SimpleClass>>` isn't an `IList<IList<SimpleClass>>`.

For example, for the latter type, you could call `lists.Add(new SimpleClass[5])` as `SimpleClass[]` implements `IList<SimpleClass>`. But you can't do that with a `List<List<SimpleClass>>`, because each element has to be a `List<SimpleClass>`.

This would be okay though:

```
List<IList<SimpleClass>> lists = new List<IList<SimpleClass>>();
```

Comment: I see clearly now. Hah. Thanks very much. I read into your other answer as well and between this post and the other. It makes sense.