# Cannot convert Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> to IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,string>>

Tags: asp.net

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> test = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

This conversion is error, why cannot implicitly `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> to IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,string>>?`

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005944/convert-listlistobject-to-ilistilistobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog ["Generic type parameter variance in the CLR"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx) which explains why conversion is not allowed.