# Generic methods overload mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

```
        private static readonly List<List<T>> data = new List<List<T>>();

        private static void ProcessData(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> data) { }

        private static void ProcessData(IEnumerable<IList<T>> data) { }

        private static void ProcessData(IList<IEnumerable<T>> data) { }

        private static void ProcessData(IList<IList<T>> data) { }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessData(data);
        }
```

1. Which overload is called?
2. Why?
3. How to call the other ones without explicit cast?

Comment: Is this a quiz question? Have you tried running this code? Have you tried doing research?

Comment: what is data in your Main function?

Comment: @Ego look at the first line of code.

Comment: if these are overload methods then I expect all are doing the same thing then you should have only one method ´private static void ProcessData(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> data) { }´ if you are trying to do this  it is wrong way to implement

Comment: Well, this is actual code from a project, I've just added a couple of overloads for research. Visual Studio shows that IEnumerable<IList<T>> overload will be called. And I have no idea why. I thought it might be 1st or 4th overload, but it's not.

Comment: That's confirmed by [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/upQLGA).

Comment: Interestingly 3 and 4 are not allowed to be called with a `List<List<string>>` (cannot convert). So 3 and 4 are out which leaves 1 and 2. Overloading goes by "best" fit, and since `IList<T>` is a better fit then `IEnumerable<T>` it ends up choosing 2.

Comment: If I change data to List<IList> 4th overload is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all see this answer of John Skeet why overloads 3 and 4 are not allowed to be called with a `List<List<string>>`: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006016/10608418

Now that 3 and 4 are out the reason 2 is chosen is because the compiler looks for the "best match": some of this is covered by Eric Lippert in this SO answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/10608418

But basically the result is that 2 is the best fit (`IList<T>` is "stronger" then `IEnumerable<T>`).