# How can I join two entities using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two models RP and RPHistory as shown below they both contains same data, How can i combine them to create single list data from the two?

```
 public class RP: 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int RPID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the second modal as

```
 public class RPHistory: 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int RPID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

I have this code to get data from RP:

```
var RPs = await Context.RP.Where(b => b.ProductID  == request.ID).ToListAsync();
```

How can i join update the above code to include RPHistory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
var RPs = await Context.RP.Where(b => b.ProductID  == request.ID)
                          .Select(x=> new {
                                           x.ID, 
                                           x.RPID, 
                                           x.Name, 
                                           x.ProductID, 
                                           History = Context.RPHistory
                                                            .Where(y=> y.RPID == x.RPID)
                                                            .ToList() //Note nested Select 
                                                                      //assuming List and 
                                                                      //there can be more 
                                                                      //than one entry
                                           }
                                  ).ToListAsync();
```

EDIT:

If you want a concrete class just do:

```
public class RpWithHistory {
  public int ID;
  public int RPID;
  public string Name;
  public int ProductID;
  public List<RPHistory> History;
}

// Then in your code:

var RPs = await Context.RP.Where(b => b.ProductID  == request.ID)
                              .Select(x=> new RpWithHistory {
                                               ID = x.ID, 
                                               RPID = x.RPID, 
                                               Name = x.Name, 
                                               ProductID = x.ProductID, 
                                               History = Context.RPHistory
                                                                .Where(y=> y.RPID 
                                                                        == x.RPID)
                                                                .ToList()
                                               }
                                      ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Matt, Thank you! I used Mapping using Automapper as var rpDTOs = Mapper.Map<IList<RPDTO>>(RPs ); and I get the exception error s Mapping types:List`1 -> IList`1. but this is what i want `

Comment: Matt, Can we cast the nested select to Ilist?

Comment: Probably not, due to covariance if I remember my CS correctly. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005944/convert-listlistobject-to-ilistilistobject.

Comment: Matt, Now i know When i get the records from the DB, the select statement is converting it into an anonymous type, which Automapper doesn't know how to convert. Can we fix that?

Comment: I don't know much about automapper and that's a different question of which I'm not sure

Comment: but is it possible to convert anonymous type to any type?

Comment: one more help i get this  `RpWithHistory.History is in accessible due to its protection level`

Comment: Sorry Matt now i get can not implicitly convert Generic.List RPHistory  to ... Generic.List. RPHistory in this line ` History = Context.RPHistory
                                                                .Where(y=> y.RPID 
                                                                        == x.RPID)
                                                                .ToList()`

Comment: I don't know - that's beyond the scope of this question. Honestly, you should try to do what you want to do without AutoMapper first, then get back to it.

Comment: I am not using Auto mapper now, i take  that part  out. Ok Thanks for the help!